# Powershell activating script on remote machine - remote machine cannot see network shares

Tags: powershell, remote-server

I have a database server not in a domain, that the task scheduler is corrupt and I don't have the time or resources to repair it yet so I created a script that runs from another non-domain server using task scheduler that activates a second script located on the database server to copy files.  On the database server the script when activated manually sees everything and does its job but when I try remotely activating the script it runs and sees everything but the network drives (W:).  I am using credssp in the script which connects fine see below - Question how can I get the script to see the network share on the remote server

-------------Script A---------------------------------------------

```
$username = "Administrator"
$computerA = "<addressA>"
$computerB = "<addressB>"
$PwdLocation = "c:\test\password.txt"
#enable-wsmancredssp -role client -delegatecomputer $computerB
$password = Get-Content $PwdLocation | ConvertTo-SecureString 
$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential - argumentlist $username,$password
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerB -ScriptBlock {\\<remote server>\test\delete.ps1} -ArgumentList $ComputerA -Credential $credential
exit
```

----------------------Remote Script B ---------------------------------------

```
Function mailer {
$recipients = "<names>"
$smtp = "smtp.org"
$emailTo = $recipients
$emailFrom = "no-reply@org.org"
$smtpserver="smtp.org" 
$smtp=New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $message)
}
Function StopEverything {
$subject = "Stopped Script Delete.PS1 becuase of no connection"
$message = ""
for($i=0;$i -le $tot-1;$i++)
{
$path = $bfs[$i]
if (Exists-Dir($path))  
{ 
$message += [string]::concat($path, " Connected`n")
} 
else 
{ 
$message += [string]::concat($path, " Cannot Connect`n")

} 
 }
mailer 
Exit
}

Function Exists-Dir($path) { 
    if ([IO.Directory]::Exists($path)) 
    { 
        return $true; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return $false; 
    } 
} 

$ScriptStart = (Get-Date)
[array]$bfs =    "F:\Backups\NetPerfMon","F:\Backups\NetPerfMon_Aux","W:\Backups\NetPerfMon_Aux","W:\Backups\NetPerfMon"
$tot = $bfs.count

for($i=0;$i -le $tot-1;$i++)
{
$path = $bfs[$i]
if (Exists-Dir($path))  
{ 
$message += [string]::concat($path, " Connected`n")
$subject = "Start Script Delete.PS1 on " + $ScriptStart
} 
else 
{ 
$message += [string]::concat($path, " Cannot Connect`n")
StopEverything
} 
 }


$message += "  "
$message += 
mailer
$limit  = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
$limit1 = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$limit2 = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$FB     = "F:\Backups\NetPerfMon"
$FBAux  = "F:\Backups\NetPerfMon_Aux"
$WBAux  = "W:\Backups\NetPerfMon_Aux"
$WBBak  = "W:\Backups\NetPerfMon"

Get-ChildItem -Path $FB     | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -     lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force | OUT-NULL #Remove items greater than 7 days
Get-ChildItem -Path $FBAux  | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force | OUT-NULL #Remove items greater than 7 days
Get-ChildItem -Path $WBBak  | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit1} | Remove-Item -Force | OUT-NULL #Remove items greater than 14 days
Get-ChildItem -Path $FB     | where {$_.extension -eq ".bak"} | Where-Object {     !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $limit2} | Copy-Item -destination $WBBak | OUT-    NULL #Copy items within 1 day that have extension .bak
Get-ChildItem -Path $FBAux  | where {$_.extension -eq ".bak"} | Where-Object {      !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $limit2} | Copy-Item -destination $WBAux | OUT-    NULL #Copy items within 1 day that have extension .bak
$ScriptEnd = (Get-Date)
$RunTime = New-Timespan -Start $ScriptStart -End $ScriptEnd
"Elapsed Time: {0}:{1}:{2}" -f $RunTime.Hours,$Runtime.Minutes,$RunTime.Seconds
$subject = "Stop Script Delete.PS1 on " + $ScriptEnd
$message = ""
$message += "  "
$message += "Time to completion: {0}:{1}:{2}" -f        $RunTime.Hours,$Runtime.Minutes,$RunTime.Seconds
mailer
```

Comment: Do you ru this script with an other user which not have the drive W:\? Can you use the UCN path  (\\server\share) and not the W:\?

Comment: Like Patrick said if credssp is actually working you should be able to use a direct UNC path. It was a common, cheesy hack to map a drive with "net use" right in the script being run in a remote ps session and then copy to that drive letter, but credssp makes this unnecessary. If delegation is working you avoid that "double-hop" error when using UNC paths. Also, is it really that much more effort to just fix the task scheduler engine than futz around with this little hack?

Answer (score 0):

Use the complete UNC paths not drive letters OR do a "net use X: \my\unc\share" at the top of your script mapping the drives right in the script.

edit: if you do this you will have to explicitly specify the password in the net use command: `net use x: \\my\share /user:mydom\myuser mypassword`